# Is there one or more marinas in Okinawa used by private yacht owners that allows non-yachties to visit?

Tags: japan, sea-travel, hitchhiking, okinawa, marinas

I've been in Naha, Okinawa for about a month, and I'm feeling it's time to move to the big islands.

But since I've hitchhiked my whole trip (except the flight from Taiwan to Okinawa), and since I've never hitchhiked a yacht yet, I'm interesting to see if I can meet some yachties who might enjoy letting me ride along.

Yes I know there are sites like [findacrew.net](http://www.findacrew.net/), but often you have to register, and I have almost no experience, so I couldn't be regarded as crew. I don't mind helping out of course, but I'm more a hitchhiker than "crew".

So please just answer helping me find such marinas, not with general tips on riding boats that could apply anywhere in the world.

(By the way, they must be Japanese civilian marinas, not ones on US bases.)

---

There is some info on marinas on the website [Sail - Okinawa](http://www.sail-okinawa.com/marinas/), but it doesn't give me any clue what kind of people use them, whether I could go in and meet people, etc. Only one of them has a website link, and even that's in Japanese only.

Comment: Marinas in Okinawa are rarely gated premises. You can normally go in anywhere except some special super-yacht berth places. You can always go there and start to talk to people.

Comment: @uncovery: You should submit this as an answer, along with how you know this I suppose. I finally left Okinawa by ferry but it will be useful to others who Google for the same kind of info (-:

Comment: @uncovery, care to drop it in as an answer?

Comment: Don't assume that because you have no experience you can't be crew. Some captains are happy with crew who will do what they are told and can learn on the job.

Answer (score 5):

Marinas in Okinawa are rarely gated premises. You can normally go in anywhere except some special super-yacht berth places. You can always go there and start to talk to people.

If you take a look at [google streetview](https://www.google.com/maps/search/marina/@26.276029,127.730161,3a,75y,327.41h,81.28t/data=!3m4!1e1!3m2!1sb6mvK5Io8_ILeO6Uyfi4_w!2e0!4m5!2m4!3m3!1smarina!2sOkinawa,+Japan!3s0x34f57062eeab5be7:0x35bb617286fdd1ef), you can see how the marinas do not have any kind of enclosures.